# Genius Mousepen i608x

Tags: tablet

I am a simple user of ubuntu. I bought a genius mousepen, and it doesn't work. It is really important to me. I tried to look after solution and there are some, but I didn't understand them. I am not an expert computer user. Ubuntu works wonderfully for me, but if I have a problem, it is a nightmare. Can anybody help me? I need step by step instruction with simple words and descriptions. I never use terminal, so if it include terminal please be very simple. I really need this, I am so desperate. If somebody could help, I would be very grateful. Thanks.

Comment: Did the answer help you? If yes, please accept it so that the others (including me) will know if we should get this tablet. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:doctormo/xorg-wizardpen
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-input-wizardpen
```

Reboot, and it should work

Otherwise other instructions (although for *archinux*), http://kokizzu.blogspot.com/2015/02/how-to-setup-genius-mousepen-i608x-in.html

Other drivers to try [DIGImend](https://github.com/DIGImend/digimend-kernel-drivers)

Comment: Unfortunately that PPA hasn't been updated in over three years. The most recently supported version of Ubuntu is Precise.